# run function based on input value - jquery

Tags: jquery, function, input

I am having a surprisingly hard time trying to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

what in trying to do is i have a bunch of functions and if "funtion1" is typed into the input feild and submited the function1 will run. if "function2" is submitted, function2 will run. thought is would be simple but i can't seem to get it.

Comment: Can you give more details?  Whats the code you currently have?  Lets see your attempt.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object array of functions, example :

```
var funcs = {
    'func1': function() {},
    'func2': function() {},
    'func3': function() {},
    'func4': function() {}
};
$(function() {
    $('a.run').click(function() {
        var f = funcs[$('#myinput').val()];
        if(f) f();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Very elegant... almost pythonic :)

Comment: tried you code here but still couldnt do it http://jsfiddle.net/LWshk/

Comment: @wil - check [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/LWshk/4/)

Comment: this works!!! thanks Onofone and Lix

Comment: My bad, I used `a` instead of `input[type="submit"]` thanks @Lix for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a `switch` statement

```
switch(document.getElementById("myinput").value) {
  case 'function1':
       // do something
  break;
  case 'function2':
       // do something else
  break;
}
```

Comment: +1 - a pre-defined list would be the only safe way to execute this.... but... not enough jQuery :P

Comment: not enough jQuery. Oops.

Comment: Also I believe it is referred to as a `switch` statement. See [oneofone's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18752378/558021) for a **great** way to bypass the need for the switch construct.

Comment: @Lix yes my mistake - edited it to reflect the real name of the control statement

Answer (score 0):

```
var functions = {
    test : function(){alert("test");}
};

$("#click").click(function () {
    var func = $("#run").val();
    console.log(functions[func] != undefined);
    if (functions[func] != undefined) {
        functions[func]();
    }
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p3tW/1/)